# display the content of clusters after clustering in streaming-k-means.scala code source in spark

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark, k-means, spark-streaming

i want to run the streaming k-means-example.scala code source (mllib) on spark , someone tell me how i can how I can display the content of clusters after clustering (for example i want to clustering data into 3 clusters , how i can display the cntent of the 3 clusters in 3 files and the content of centers in file.txt)

```
           package org.apache.spark.examples.mllib

           import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
           import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans
           import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
           import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
           import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}  


           object StreamingKMeansExample {

        def main(args: Array[String]) {
        if (args.length != 5) {
        System.err.println(  "Usage: StreamingKMeansExample " +
  "<trainingDir> <testDir> <batchDuration> <numClusters>       <numDimensions>")
     System.exit(1)
       }
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("localhost").setAppName
     ("StreamingKMeansExample")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(args(2).toLong))

val trainingData = ssc.textFileStream(args(0)).map(Vectors.parse)
val testData = ssc.textFileStream(args(1)).map(LabeledPoint.parse)

 val model = new StreamingKMeans().setK(args(3).toInt)
 .setDecayFactor(1.0)
 .setRandomCenters(args(4).toInt, 0.0)

   model.trainOn(trainingData)
 model.predictOnValues(testData.map(lp => (lp.label,   lp.features))).print()

 ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the predict method on your RDD( [look here for reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel))
Then you could zip your Rdd containing values and your RDD of predicted clusters they fall in.